# Свойства max-width и min-width

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

верстал страницу и наткнулся на проблему - при ширине меньше 1400пх, слой с изображениями залазит под слой с списком. Хотя свойства `max-width` и `min-width` установлены размер слоя остаётся статическим (неизменным)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тоже самое происходит и с изображениями внутри слоя Content
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
    background-image: url(http://fotohost.by/images/2015/09/23/BGI.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 14pt;
}

.Conteiner {
    margin: auto;
    height: 4000px;
    max-width: 1380px;
    min-width: 980px;
}


.Categories {
    width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFE5;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFFFE5;
    position: absolute;
}

.Content {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 1160px;
    min-width: 744px;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0.94;
    background-color: white;
    float: right;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
a:visited {
    color: black; 
   }
ol {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
li:hover {
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
}
li {
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #818A8F;
    padding: 10px 8px 8px 11px;
}
img {
    max-width: 228px;
    min-height: 198px;
}
```

```html
<html><head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/App_Themes/Styles/MaterPageStyles.css">
    <title>MasterPages</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Conteiner">

        <div class="Content">
            
<img src="http://fotohost.by/images/2015/09/23/941b9af0bbdbef2d.png" />
<img src="http://fotohost.by/images/2015/09/23/941b9af0bbdbef2d.png" />
<img src="http://fotohost.by/images/2015/09/23/941b9af0bbdbef2d.png" />
<img src="http://fotohost.by/images/2015/09/23/941b9af0bbdbef2d.png" />
<img src="http://fotohost.by/images/2015/09/23/941b9af0bbdbef2d.png" />
<img src="http://fotohost.by/images/2015/09/23/941b9af0bbdbef2d.png" />

        </div>

        <div class="Categories">
            <a href="/Home/Index"><img width="220" height="220" src="http://fotohost.by/images/2015/09/23/941b9af0bbdbef2d.png" style="border-radius: 220px;" /></a>
            <div style="padding: 5px 0px 5px 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #c5c4c4; background-color: #F4F3F1">
                Категории
            </div>
            <ol>
                <a href="http/vk.com/"><li>Игрушки до 60см</li></a>
                <li>Игрушки от 60см до 80см</li>
                <li>Игрушки от 80см до 100см</li>
                <li>Игрушки от 100см до 160см</li>
                <li>Игрушки от 160см до 180см</li>
                <li>Игрушки от 180 см до 200см</li>
                <li> Игрушки выше 200см</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>


</body></html>
```

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, в чём суть Вашего вопроса, и чего Вы хотите добиться.

Comment: @Rolandius Суть в том, что я хочу чтобы div с именем класса `"Content"` изменялся в размерах и не залазил под div с именем класса `"Categories"`, а тот в свою очередь оставался неизменным. Чтобы пользователь если решил изменить размер окна браузера не увидел кашу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Виноват position: absolute; он выносит блок из потока.

Вы не правильно собрали колонки вот здесь есть [примеры различных раскладок](http://htmlbook.ru/layout)
[Простой пример раскладки от меня (фиксированная и полу резиновая колонка)](http://codepen.io/Zoxon/pen/JYRWOB)

```css
.page__wrapper {
  max-width: 1380px;
  min-width: 980px;
  margin: auto;
}
.page__sidebar {
  width: 220px;
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  background: #add8e6;
}
.page__content {
  margin-left: 220px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #90ee90;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="page__wrapper">
    <div class="page__sidebar"></div>
    <div class="page__content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас к классу `"Categories"` применён `position:absolute`, к классу `"Content"`применено свойство `float:right`. Поэтому при уменьшении размера экрана левый блок остаётся, а правый уезжает под него.

Мне кажется странным выбранный вами подход в вёрстке. Быть может, лучше сверстать без `position:absolute`? Если вы не преследуете какие-то специфические цели, конечно.

Comment: Требуется чтобы `"Categories"` не изменялось в размерах, а изменялся только класс `"Content"`, если я уберу `position:absolute`, то элемент уже не на своём месте

Comment: @Алексей можете вот так попробовать: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4euk2Lr/)

Answer (score 0):

Вашу проблему можно решить добавив в класс `.Content` свойство `margin-left: 220px;`, размер навигации же известен, так мы сделаем отступ от левой колонки.

Но в Вашем случае гораздо корректнее было бы разбить весь макет на два столбца. Левый с навигацией и правый с контентом. Тогда можно легко уйти от `position: absolute;` в `.Categories`. Примеров с такими сетками в интернете достаточно, советую разобраться с ними, это сильно облегчит Вам жизнь, особенно, если  Вы хотите, чтобы страница хорошо выглядела при разных размерах окна браузера.